# why tmux under ansi-term so slow?

Tags: eshell, ansi-term, performance, comint

I use colorized output in `ghci`. And if run it:

- in `comint-mode`, or in `eshell`, then colors displayed
  fine, but a lot of escape sequences displayed like `^A^Bλ ^A^B> ^A^B^B`.
- in `ansi-term`, then I got much better result like `λ > ^B`.
- in `tmux` in `ansi-term` it displayed perfect (like colored `λ >`) but except performance.

Why output speed reduced so significant in this case?

---

*Not sure if this information may be helpful:* `emacs` launched under `tmux` (surely, it in different `tmux`session, than that in `ansi-term` with `ghci`) in `rxvt-unicode` terminal emulator.

---

**UPD:** prompt example `:set prompt "\001\ESC[33m\002λ \001\ESC[01;34m\002> \001\ESC[m\002\STX"`

Comment: "in `comint-mode`[...] a lot of escape sequences[...]" - have you tried `ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on`?

Comment: Whenever I use tmux in any of the terminals I get weird visuals and effects when I type clear. Do any of the terminals (dumb or otherwise) actually work?

Comment: @npostavs `ELISP> ansi-color-for-comint-mode
t
`

Comment: @JulesTamagnan yes, in plain `urxvt` and `tmux` all just fine.

Comment: more pointers at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41227

Comment: Seems like, despite `comint-mode` understand color codes and change face properties, it still display unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> twb knows all!  Tell your friends!

*Thanks to helpful advises from @twb from #emacs IRC channel. Here's solution for such cases.* Bug was in escape sequences which used use for `ghci` promt. It was expect that terminal will be `xterm`-compatible. But it don't. More proper way is to use `tput` like `set_fg_red=$(tput setaf 1) reset=$(tput sgr0)` or check `$TERM` for compatibility (such like vt100, dumb, emacs).